# Create new column with a certain value for those entries that fulfill one condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame , imagine the following toy example:

```
A | B | C
1   2   4
3   2   1
3   1   2
```

and I want to create a third attribute (e.g D) that is set to 1 or 0
if a entity attribute (e.g A)  equals to something, e.g 3:

```
A | B | C | D
1   2   4   0
3   2   1   1
3   1   2   1
```

Which function/assignment can I use?

Comment: Use `as.integer(df1$A == 3)`

Comment: Thanks! @akrun that was what I was looking for!